# How to run a job in detached mode in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

Can someone please tell me how to run a job in detached mode ? A job in my pipeline takes 30 minutes to complete, I want the pipeline to proceed without waiting for this job to complete.

For example:

```
stages:
  - build
  - build2
  - test
newservice:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build is done"
newservice1:
  stage: build2
  script:
    - echo "build1 is done"
    - sleep 60
mygotservice:
  stage: test
  needs: ["newservice"]
  script:
    - echo "test is done"
```

I want the pipeline to proceed ahead without waiting for newservice1.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many reasons...
running tests may take time.
Where is the server? Where to get resources?
There are many possible reasons and it is not just about the git...